# Is Full text indexing for high transaction responses a good idea?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

For example, in order to provide an effective way to query repsondents answers to a dynamic questionnaire, where responses are stored in a keyword/response pair.

I am aware that there may be some latency in updating the catalogue/text index as new entries are added, but this may not matter if reporting/querying is not a real time concern. (i.e. performed at some later date)

So in answer to my own question, the transactional aspect of this doesnt actually matter, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would distinguish between data consistency in selected storage and gap between data arrival and appearing in search results for the user as you might use external or even remote search solutions for your application as the index update might take some significant time depends on the case.

Comment: I think in the use case I have in mind, it would be acceptable for results to not have to appear immediately, Or I could use a fallback -but the fallback would, in effect, negate the benefits of the performance I get from the former implementation.  However, I could offer explicit "quick" and "extended" search options....

Comment: If you business requirements says that you need to keep data consistent and at the same time documents might not appear for user at arrival time then you can actually use transactional storage for the data with no slow parts like full-text indexes which will guarantee you maximum safety and use another place (database or external search engine or service) to perform actual search queries.